# Is it okay to use one angular service from another?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have 2 services and 1 component:

**Services**

- AuthService
- ProductService

**Component**

- ProductSubmitComponent

`ProductService.postProduct` method does a `POST` request to an API endpoint that requires a `token` parameter which can be obtained via `AuthService.get_token()` method. `ProductService` needs to be used in `ProductSubmitComponent` to submit new products.

**There are 2 ways to do this**

1.
`ProductService` imports and uses `AuthService` to get the token without the `ProductSubmitComponent` having to care about passing `token` as an explicit parameter.

OR

2.
`ProductService.postProduct` method takes `token` as an explicit input parameter which must be provided by the `ProductSubmitComponent` as an additional argument when requesting the service method.

Both these ways should work, but my dilemma is, which one should I adopt? This question effectively boils down to:

Is it okay to use one angular service within another **vs** services being strictly used from directives/components only and not other services?

Comment: I have this question too and reading a lot of opinions about it. Can I ask you what are you using *now* and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on the situation. If you think you are going to use the `ProductService.postProduct` method in other components as well, it is much more efficient to have `ProductService` import the `AuthService`.

To my knowledge, it's not bad practice to use one service in another one. I'm pretty sure your `AuthService` injects the `Http` service, which is basically the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

You should ask yourself, if you need the token in the component.

If not, then the component shouldn't care about the implementation detail - all it wants is to post a product after all. So if the ProductService can obtain the token by itself it very well should do this.

Also ...

- ... it's easier to mock that service in your unit tests
- ... no duplicate code all over the place

Comment: This makes sense. I recall now reading articles that emphasize `Auth` needs to be pluggable. The article was for backend REST APIs but I think the same design pattern would be good to follow for a client side app as well. Answer by @PierreDuc that I accepted being a minute earlier is similar to yours. Both nice answers.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping every service loosely coupled is the best coding practice. Your second way meets it. If you apply first method, then `ProductService` will be tightly coupled.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine that a service can be dependent on another service.

However, I would personally look into making the `AuthService` capable of changing the default request headers so that it automatically includes the token on each request to your API if you're not doing cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a meaningful an well documented dependency injection hierarchy I would simply inject everything. In the long run, this will make testing easier as there are well-known dependencies where you can see at a glance what needs to be provided or mocked.